# Were there serfs in early 20th century in south of Spain?

Tags: 20th-century, slavery, spain

So, here is the deal,

My grandad fled Andalusia in 1934 when he was a little kid with his mother. For what he told me he and his mother they were practically serfs. Working for a rich man, sleeping in the barn and being forbidden to leave the place.

But I cannot get source to validate that they were serfs at this time in Spain. Officially, I know it was forbidden many years before.

So if anyone can tell me a bit more about it, how likely and spread it was, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It really depends on what you call serf... In your grandad's story, what is unique about working for the rich and paid for peanuts?

Comment: There definitely were serfs. For a very good approach on how this could be, you can watch the movie [Los santos inocentes (The Holy Innocents)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Holy_Innocents_(film)).

Comment: Human trafficking and slavery are true even today;  While there may not have been legal serfs, I'd be quite surprised if there were not illicit labor practices in 1930's Spain